# Difficulty in getting count of a simple query

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with 1118 records. In these records there is one field `flag` which is by default NULL. 556 of these records have field `flag` marked as true while the rest are NULL.
When I run the following query :

```
select count(*) from table_name where flag!='true'
```

I get result as 0. Where as actual result should be 1118-556 i.e 562.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use tinyint to define bool case fields as well as 1 and 0, 0 for null cases and 1 for true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL never compares to anything, not even another NULL

```
select count(*) from table_name where flag!='true' OR flag IS NULL
```

or

```
select count(*) from table_name where flag IS NULL
```

It depends if you have another value apart from `true` (`false`?) as well as NULLs

```
select
    count(CASE WHEN flag = 'true' THEN flag END) AS truecount,
    count(CASE WHEN flag = 'false' THEN flag END) AS falsecount
    count(*) - count(flag) AS NULLCount
from 
    table_name
```

Finally, see these to understand COUNT and null/not null values

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2512/630
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221649/27535

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

In Queries NULL will never be matched by any boolean expression unless mentioned explicit:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE flag IS NULL
```